# Как сделать поиск в Many2Many field Django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

У меня есть поле many2manyfield в классе Checks, которые берутся из класса Tovar, но товаров в Tovar более 100 000 , поэтому я не могу выбрать те товары, которые мне нужны, потому что не могу их найти, как мне сделать поиск в поле Manhy to many field по Id или имени?

Comment: `Checks.objects.filter(tovars__in=[•••])` где в списке вы можете указать Id которые вы хотели бы извлечь

Comment: Не, мне нужно, чтобы можно было сделать поиск в админке по Id товаров